# Operator LIKE in LUCENE

Tags: sql, lucene.net, lucene, zend-search-lucene

I'm working in Lucene 4.6 and i'm trying to look for records that contains "keyword1" in "field1" and "keyword2" in "field2"
I wrote following query:

```
Query q = MultifieldQueryParser.parse(
    Version.Lucene_46, 
    new String[] {keyword1, keyword2}, 
    new String[]{"field1","field2"}, 
    new StandardAnalyzer()
);
```

That gives me some results but I want to have something like %keyword1% , %keyword2% in SQL.

---

Thanks for your answers. In case I have a field with the value "Lucene Game Lucene" and I'm looking for that document using the keyword "Game" I can't get that result using *keyword neither keyword* Who have any idea about this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [WildcardQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/WildcardQuery.html). Supported wildcards are `*`, which matches any character sequence (including the empty one), and `?`, which matches any single character. `\` is the escape character.

You can also use the wildcard as prefix, for example `*nix`, but that can very slow on large indexes, because Lucene needs to scan the entire list of `Terms`.

[edit]

If you need a prefix wildcard in the queryparser, make sure to call `setAllowLeadingWildcard(true)` 
on the `QueryParser` [As can be seen here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParserBase.html#setAllowLeadingWildcard%28boolean%29)

Comment: you can not search with `*` in beginning of the search word http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package_description.

Comment: Yes you can, but you need to explicitly allow it (for performance reasons)

Comment: kindly share any link or resource for doing that cause I am totally unaware about it

Comment: Ok! I guess I had it all wrong about wildcard not being allowed at beginning of term, that reduces a lot work. Its a trade off for performance but handy one

Answer (score 1):

WildcardQuery in Lucene provides the possibility to search for keyword%. For the other way arount there is some work to be done during indexing. You need to index the terms in reversed form (in an other field) and perform the query drowyek%.

Comment: Is there any other way around without creating mirror field? cause I am also looking for solution for this quite some time as maintaining one more field and possibly one more query each time is inconvenient

Comment: When search speed is not important for you, you can create your own query class which iterates through all terms and checks whether your criteria matches. This is a brute-force approach which will be slow. If you insist on not wanna change the indexing behavior, then this is the way to go. You can of course make performance optimizations e.g. by putting the terms into memory-cache or in a synced datastructure allowing your search criteria to be performed fast.

Comment: Lucene provides ways to do exactly as the user asked. See my answer.

Comment: seems to be a new feature in lucene 4. thanx. but to solve the performance issue, you still need to index the terms in reversed form.

Comment: @faith I'm certain it's been around since [at least 2.9](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/api/contrib-queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/standard/StandardQueryParser.html#setAllowLeadingWildcard(boolean)).